# Ant regex compare in if condition

Tags: regex, ant, string-comparison

I have `str1="A sample string"`. If the `str1` contains `sample`, I need to `echo` something like `match` and otherwise `not matching`. I am not familiar with [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) scripts. Please help me.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using newer ant, try... 
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html

```
<condition property="legal-password">
  <matches pattern="[1-9]" string="${user-input}"/>
</condition>
<fail message="Your password should at least contain one number"
      unless="legal-password"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

If you just want to know if a substring exists in the string, you can use `<contains>` task together with `<if>` task from **ant-contrib**. If you want to scan for a pattern (a regexp) in a string, use `<matches>` instead of `<contains>`.

Check for examples in this page: [Ant Manual: Condition Tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html)

Also, a example:

```
<if>
    <contains string="a sample string" substring="sample" />
    <then>
        <echo>match</echo>
    </then>
    <else>
        <echo>not match</echo>
    </else>
</if>
```